# What does さっさ mean?

Tags: words

What does さっさ mean?

> おやこうこう ひやさっさ、よいさっさ、

I can't find a definition.

Answer (score 11):

「さっさ」 does **not** have any meanings; It is just a common 囃子言葉{はやしことば}.

囃子言葉 is a nonsense/meaningless refrain used in certain songs for the purpose of keeping a good rhythm.

For instance, listen to this well-known children's song:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBDiYtsRevU

and you will notice that about half of the lyrics is 囃子言葉.

Finally, this 「さっさ」 has absolutely nothing to do with the 「さっさ」 discussed in  [this recent Q&A](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65995/distinction-between-%e6%97%a9%e9%80%9f-and-%e3%81%95%e3%81%a3%e3%81%95%e3%81%a8).